# What difference does it makes to parse something as an object literal rather than as a block?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for my ignorance on JavaScript basic concepts.

It boils down to this:

> Literal - A value found directly in the script. Examples:

```
3.14
"This is a string"
[2, 4, 6]
```

> Expression - A group of tokens, often literals or identifiers, combined
>   with operators that can be evaluated to a specific value. Examples:

```
2.0
"This is a string"
(x + 2) * 4
```

There is a very clear difference b/w the above two in Javascript.

I happen to read this [article](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/). And I am familiar with the difference b/w `function declaration` & `function expression` and when to use one over other or vice-versa.

From the same article:

> ....You might also recall that when evaluating JSON with eval, the string
>   is usually wrapped with parenthesis — eval('(' + json + ')'). This is
>   of course done for the same reason — grouping operator, which
>   parenthesis are, forces JSON brackets to be parsed as expression
>   rather than as a block:

```
try {
  { "x": 5 }; // "{" and "}" are parsed as a block
} catch(err) {
  // SyntaxError
}

({ "x": 5 }); // grouping operator forces "{" and "}" to be parsed as object literal
```

So, what difference does it make to parse something as an `object literal` other than parsing them as a `block`?

And for what purpose should I consider to make use of `grouping character`, in context of `parsing`?

Comment: A block is a kind of *statement*, neither expression nor literal. You'll want to look that up as well :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't `eval` *JSON*, use `JSON.parse` on the *String* source

---

A block is a *"group of expressions"* for example,

```
let x = 0;
if (true) {
    // this is a block
    ++x;
}
```

However, equally this is also a block

```
let x = 0;
{ // hi there, I'm a block!
    ++x;
}
```

This means when the interpreter sees block notation, it assumes a block even if you do something like this

```
{ // this is treated as a block
    foo: ++x
}
```

Here, `foo` acts as a *label* rather than a property name and if you try to do more complex things with the attempted object literal, you're going to get a *Syntax Error*.

When you want to write an *Object literal* ambiguously like this, the solution is to force the interpreter into *"expression mode"* explicitly by providing parenthesis

```
({ // this is definately an Object literal
    foo: ++x
})
```

Comment: The "_expression mode_" is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A group that begins with a `{` and ends with a `}` is treated as either object literal or a block depending on context*.

Within an expression context the group is interpreted as an object literal. Writing a block within an expression context will generate a syntax error:

```
// Valid code:
foo = {a:b};
({a:b});

// Syntax errors:
foo = {var a = b};
({var a = b});
```

Outside of an expression context the group is interpreted as a block. Depending on exactly how the code is written, an object literal written outside of an expression context is either a syntax error or will be interpreted as a label.

*note: In the ECMAscript spec the word "context" is used to mean something specific. My use of the word here is with the general meaning in computer science with regards to parsing.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. What do you mean by the term label here..[ will be interpreted as a label]?

Comment: A label is an identifier-like thing which can be used in `break` and `continue` statements etc

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari: https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label. If you read the documentation you will notice that labels have similar syntax to object keys in object literal. So it is possible for a block containing a label to look like a simple object literal.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari: FWIW, labels are a language feature that was inherited from assembly language